# xml using Python: Identify whether the last of specified tag is reached

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a large ..xml file with many items closed by a tag, like `MATCH`. Also, there are other tags too at same level as `MATCH`, like `STATISTIC`, so the xml file would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MAIN>
<SOME_TAG info="some_tag" >
<TAG value="0" />
</SOME_TAG>
<MATCH match="match_1" >
<ITEM item="1" />
</MATCH>
<MATCH match="match_2" >
<ITEM item="2" />
</MATCH>
<MATCH match="match_3" >
<ITEM item="3" />
</MATCH>
<STATISTIC stat="stat_1" >
<VALUE value="1" />
</STATISTIC>
<STATISTIC stat="stat_2" >
<VALUE value="2" />
</STATISTIC>
<STATISTIC stat="stat_3" >
<VALUE value="3" />
</STATISTIC>
<ANOTHER_TAG info="another_tag" >
<TAG value="0" />
</ANOTHER_TAG>
</MAIN>
```

I want to read all contents closed in tags `MATCH` and `STATISTIC`. My code is something like

```
import lxml.etree as etree

def read_xml(xml_file):
    context = etree.iterparse(xml_file, events=["end"], recover=True)
    my_intests = []
    for event, element in context:
        if element.tag == "MATCH":
            for match_elem in element.findall("ITEM"):
                my_intests.append(match_elem.get("item"))
            element.clear()
            for ancestor in element.xpath("ancestor-or-self::*"):
                while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                    del ancestor.getparent()[0]
        elif element.tag == "STATISTIC":
            for stat_elem in element.findall("VALUE"):
                my_intests.append(stat_elem.get("value"))
            element.clear()
            for ancestor in element.xpath("ancestor-or-self::*"):
                while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                    del ancestor.getparent()[0]
        elif element.tag == "ANOTHER_TAG":
            element.clear()
            break
    print(my_intests) # print: ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

After finishing reading `STATISTIC`, all `element` will not be `clear`ed, thus will be very slow if there are many tags after tag `ANOTHER_TAG`.

One possible solution is firstly call `context = etree.iterparse(xml_file, events=["end"], recover=True, tag="MATCH")` for reading all `MATCH` tags, then call `context = etree.iterparse(xml_file, events=["end"], recover=True, tag="STATISTIC")` for all `STATISTIC` tags, but have to go through the file twice, or more if I want to read other tags.

I can also use `if element.tag=="ANOTHER_TAG"` and `break` to stop reading, as I have done here. But I may be intested `ANOTHER_TAG` too later, so would be not optimal to find out what is the tag after all tags I'm intested and then `break`. The xml file tags may be changed too in future.

So I think a better solution can have a `if all(tag in {"MATCH", "STATISTIC"}) have been processed` check, instead of `if element.tag=="ANOTHER_TAG"` here, then `break` to finish the reading. Any way to do this?

Comment: Please add to your question a desired output

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks. The question has been edited.

Comment: The provided XML is not well-formed. Please fix it

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky modified.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are over-complicating this a bit. Try it this way:

```
vals = context.xpath('//STATISTIC/VALUE/@value')
items = context.xpath('//MATCH/ITEM/@item')
my_intests=vals+items
print(my_intests)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```